# Diff, ignore added lines to right file

Tags: shell, unix, diff, gnu

Is there a way to have diff ignore added lines to second files but still report lines that are different or missing in the second file?

File1:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

File2:

```
line1
line2
extra line
line3
extra line
line4
```

File2:

```
line2
extra line
line3
extra line
line5
```

Desired result:

diff File1 File2 -> returns exit 0

diff File1 File3 -> returns exit 1

Comment: Are the lines sorted?

Comment: no they are not but I can sort them using sort fairly easily

Comment: then `sort` then pass to `comm` and get only unique lines in the first file, then check if the output is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [diff -u](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) ?

It doesn't quite do what you want, but gives you a building block you could use for a script to do what you want.

So first two samples (you can see what's added) -

```
diff -u t1.txt t2.txt 
--- t1.txt  2021-03-15 08:42:48.000000000 +1100
+++ t2.txt  2021-03-15 08:42:56.000000000 +1100
@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 line1
 line2
+extra line
 line3
+extra line
 line4
```

And second and third examples (you can see what's removed and what's changed)

```
diff -u t2.txt t3.txt 
--- t2.txt  2021-03-15 08:42:56.000000000 +1100
+++ t3.txt  2021-03-15 08:45:41.000000000 +1100
@@ -1,6 +1,5 @@
-line1
 line2
 extra line
 line3
 extra line
-line4
+line5
```